# Samsung S7 Oreo upgrade decreased screenshots quality

Tags: 8.0-oreo, screenshots

I did this week the Oreo upgrade on my Samsung S7 device. When I'm now taking a screenshot, the file is in JPG instead of PNG and the quality is just terrible.

I really need to revert back to the higher quality screenshots, I'm publishing crops of the screenshots on my own website. I simply cannot bring to my users such bad image quality.

Had a look to the Advanced settings parameters, but nothing I can change except something called "Smart capture" which seems not related to my problem.

To demonstrate what I mean, here is a 100x100 pixel crop from Android 8 version and from Android 7 version. The left part of the image is the bad quality screenshot from Oreo, the right part is what I had before the system upgrade.

[image: screenshot quality comparison]

I don't care about the JPG or PNG format, but the quality is mandatory.

Any hints to set the quality back to the original ? 
Can anyone tell me if this "nice" feature is something from Oreo or from Samsung Experience 9.0 which came with the Oreo upgrade ? I suspect the latter (would lead me to stock Android if this is the case).

Thanks in advance !