# Screenshot as PNG instead of JPEG?

Tags: screenshots, samsung-galaxy-s-9

Is there a way to teach a Samsung Galaxy S9+ with Android 9 (Pie) to generate screenshots as PNG files instead of JPEG files? I was looking for such a configuration option (in Settings) but came up empty-handed.

My device isn't rooted and I'd like to avoid rooting, if possible.

**NB:** My question is somewhat related to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/197854/9993), but I am indeed looking for a way to revert to PNG as a lossless default format, so I'd hold *this* is not a duplicate. I also scoured questions on the [screenshots](/questions/tagged/screenshots) tag, but nothing useful there either.

Comment: Default file extension on my moto x4(pie) is PNG and on xiaomi Redmi 3s is JPG.  PNG file size on moto x4 (1080p resolution) is 119 KB and that of JPG in redmi 3s (720p) is 179 KB. I think its device specific, and png is lighter than jpg, may be that's the reason.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I also don't know a way how to configure the format used by the system screenshot function that can be triggered via **Volume-Down + Power**.

However if you can trigger your screenshots via adb and the `screencap` command let you choose which image format is used. You can select if by the file extension:

```
screencap /sdcard/screenshot1.png
```

If you don't use a .png file extension you seem to get the raw pixel data with a small header in front containing width, height, pixel-format and the color-space (SRGB, DISPLAY_P3 or UNKNOWN).

Comment: Not really. `screencap /sdcard/screenshot1.jpg` captures a (unknown?) data file in Android 10.